# Нехватка TCP портов! Как решить проблему с нехваткой портов

Tags: linux, веб-программирование, сеть, сокет, веб-сервер

Есть сервер Nginx он слушает 80 порт на вход HTTP запросов, для ответа клиенту он тоже создает сокет , отвечает и допустим закрывает ,  все ОС выделяет 65536 , значит мы можем на одной ОС принять одновременно только это число клиентов , если мне нужно 80.000 портов в пределах одной ОС кк я могу этого добиться ?

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP запросов, для ответа клиенту он тоже создает сокет , отвечает и допустим закрывает , все ОС выделяет 65536 , значит мы можем на одной ОС принять одновременно только это число клиентов

Нет, это не так: сокет, возвращаемый из `accept()` сам по себе не использует «дополнительного» порта. Так что количество клиентов одного сервера ни как не ограничивается количеством портов TCP/UDP. Количеством портов, по сути, ограничивает только количество различных программ-серверов и клиентских соединений на одном узле сети.

HTTP также не предусматривает дополнительных портов для передачи данных. Так что ни каких скрытых дополнительных портов/сокетов он также не создаёт.

Описанное выше явление встречается, например, в пассивном режиме FTP, где данные, действительно, передаются через отдельное соединение на отдельный порт, открываемый сервером, но там количество одновременных скачиваний обычно ограничено куда сильнее по соображениям производительности сервера. Так что в случае подобных протоколов приходится только смирится с ограничениями.

Comment: По-другому , представим что у меня мощный сервер , могу ли я на нем запустить 80.000 одновременных клиентских соединений ? Один узел сети , это один внешний IP ?

Comment: а proxy_pass ?)

Comment: @ИгорьДанко, да, при правильной настройке и при достатке ресурсов принципиальных ограничений на количество соединений практически нет (на  linux AFAIK оно упирается в максимальное количество файловых файловых дескрипторов и состовляет, в конфигурации ядра по умолчанию, ~2^20 на процесс )... и да, один узел, можно считать, — один ip

Comment: @eri мм??......

Answer (score 0):

Если кратко, то используется пара (ip, port) и при ответе nginx посылает ответ с (0.0.0.0,80) на (123.123.123.123, 45356) и может принимать соединений больше 80 000.

Но есть 2 момента как это можно сломать.

Перед сервером стоит роутер с snat - тогда порты закончатся в нём.

nginx настроен на proxy_pass в бэкэнд сервер на tcp сокет - тогда нему потребуется открыть новое соединение с бэкэндом (не с клиентом) и там уже кончатся порты. В этом случае надо переходить на unix сокеты вместо tcp или увеличивать число серверов в proxy_pass

Comment: может быть одновременный ответ  с 0.0.0.0:80 на 12.12.12.12:5555 и на 11.11.11.11:5555?

Comment: да, конечно. это будут разные соединения

Comment: @eri, а ты уверен, что в случае с `proxy_pass` nginx для **каждого** клиента открывает новое соединение с бекэндом, а не просто постоянно общается с ним через одно - несколько?

Comment: одно и тоже соединение по tcp может переиспользоваться, но при одновременном подключении коннекты , в лучшем случае, встанут в очередь. http байдизайн не поддерживает параллельную передачу 2х ответов

Comment: @eri, это понятно... в том то и вопрос, случится ли в этом случае туева хуча соединений, которая исчерпает порты (о чём, как я понял, спрашивает оп) или nginx использует только некоторое разумное количество соединений с бекэндом и ставит запросы в очередь?